# Error when trying to pass arguments to Azure Powershell task

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a powerShell script that I'm trying to run in Azure DevOps using an Azure PowerShell taks. This script take in 4 parameters as follows:

```
param([string] $webappname = "Null", 
      [string] $storagename = "Null", 
    [string] $container = "Null", 
    [string] $resourcegroup = "Null")

# Get the storage account.
$storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
-Name $storagename
```

In my release I'm using an Azure PowerShell script FilePath task which is configured with the Script Path and Script Arguments shown below

[image]

When running the release this fails with the following error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: According to your error message. `SetWebAppBackups.ps1` does not know what param `webappname` is. Do you happen to have these parameters inside of a function?

Comment: Check `(Get-Command SetWebAppBackups.ps1).Parameters` (use full path to  `SetWebAppBackups.ps1` if  necessary).